# Looping to add value=1 a time to all requirement field in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, loops, inventory

I have a screenshot of excel below:
[image: allocate]
below is the scenario:

- total of stock is 20, total of order=33
- FIFO based on Order Type and
- Datetime the stock must be shared by FIFO to all order by qty=1 by qty=1

I got solution from this site with the query below:

```
DECLARE @tblOrder TABLE
    (DealerCode NVARCHAR(50),
     PartCode NVARCHAR(50),
     OrderQty INT,
     OrderType NVARCHAR(50),
     OrderDt DATETIME
    )
INSERT  INTO @tblOrder
        ( DealerCode,
          PartCode,
          OrderQty,
          OrderType,
          OrderDt)
VALUES  ('D1','A',1,'Hotline','2015-04-23'),
('D2','A',5,'Urgent','2015-04-24'),
('D3','A',3,'Normal','2015-04-25'),
('D4','A',13,'Normal','2015-04-26'),
('D5','A',9,'Normal','2015-04-27'),
('D6','A',2,'Normal','2015-04-28');

DECLARE @tblStock TABLE
    (PartCode NVARCHAR(50),
     StockQty INT)
INSERT  INTO @tblStock
        ( PartCode,
          StockQty)
VALUES  ('A',20);

;WITH ordertemp AS (
select ord.dealercode, 
      ord.partcode, 
      ord.orderqty, 
      ord.ordertype,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY case ord.ordertype when 'HotLine' then 1 when 'Urgent' then 2 else 3 end, ord.partcode, ord.OrderDt) 'StockPriority',
      sto.stockqty 'InitialStock',ord.OrderDt
from @tblorder ord
left outer join @tblstock sto
on ord.partcode = sto.partcode)

SELECT
    Orders.dealercode,
    Orders.partcode,
    CASE    WHEN Backlog.PriorQty > Orders.InitialStock THEN 0
            ELSE Orders.InitialStock - Backlog.PriorQty END 'Stock',
    Orders.orderqty,
    CASE    WHEN Backlog.PriorQty + Orders.OrderQty < Orders.InitialStock THEN Orders.OrderQty 
            WHEN Backlog.PriorQty > Orders.InitialStock THEN 0
            ELSE Orders.InitialStock - Backlog.PriorQty END 'Allocated',
    Orders.ordertype,OrderDt
FROM 
    ordertemp Orders
    INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT A.stockpriority, A.partcode, ISNULL(SUM(B.orderqty),0) 'PriorQty'
    from ordertemp A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ordertemp B
    on A.partcode = B.partcode
    and A.stockpriority > B.stockpriority 
    group by A.stockpriority, A.partcode ) Backlog
    ON Orders.stockpriority = Backlog.stockpriority
ORDER BY Orders.StockPriority
```

the result:

```
dealercode  partcode    Stock   orderqty    Allocated   ordertype   OrderDt
D1  A   20  1   1   Hotline 4/23/2015 0:00
D2  A   19  5   5   Urgent  4/24/2015 0:00
D3  A   14  3   3   Normal  4/25/2015 0:00
D4  A   11  13  11  Normal  4/26/2015 0:00
D5  A   0   9   0   Normal  4/27/2015 0:00
D6  A   0   2   0   Normal  4/28/2015 0:00
```

this result is correct but I prefer to have stock share to all orders like this:

```
dealercode  partcode    Stock   orderqty    Allocated   ordertype   OrderDt
D1  A   20  1   1   Hotline 4/23/2015 0:00
D2  A   19  5   5   Urgent  4/24/2015 0:00
D3  A   14  3   3   Normal  4/25/2015 0:00
D4  A   11  13  5   Normal  4/26/2015 0:00
D5  A   6   9   4   Normal  4/27/2015 0:00
D6  A   2   2   2   Normal  4/28/2015 0:00
```

I think i should use loop in the query to share stock qty=1 to all orders for all parts, then next until stock=0. but i have no idea to code this...pls help me out :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify exactly how you are going to allocate existing stock to outstanding orders. I can sort of see what you are trying to do, but since you haven't specified it exactly I don't actually know - and until you specify it yourself I don't think you do.

What happens if there is another order for 10? Or 1? Or 100?

Once you can write out the rule for allocating stock to the orders you should be able to code it. If you can't write out the rule, you can't code it.

Comment: the rule is looping stock by allocated qty=1 to all orders, next also qty=1,...till stock zero. if the allocated qty=order qty then qty=0 else qty=1. this looping using FIFO by ordertype and datetime. the reason to allocated qty=1 a time is to make sure every order should has stock.